# Exclamation mark on Developer Story tab

Tags: bug, profile-page, developer-story, accounts, warning-message

There is a little exclamation sign beside my *Developer Story* in my Stack Overflow account:

[image: Exclamation mark]

But when I click the Developer Story tab, the exclamation mark disappears. And there's nothing wrong with my Developer Story:

[image: Exclamation mark disappear]

I know it might sound simple, but every single time I open up my profile, it's catching my attention (and of course is a little bit annoying).

What is causing this to appear, and how do I make it go away?

Comment: This question needs an exclamation sign to warn about JPEG compression!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And there's nothing wrong with my Developer Story.

Are you sure? I have my developer story tab with an exclamation mark, and Stack Overflow does not show any suggestion when I click it, but I knew I did not complete my profile when I saw this picture:

[image]

Yep, **finish your profile**. That's it.

Comment: Ooo... I got it. I never thought about that solution before. And also I didn't notice about "Finish your profile" section in the bottom-right corner before, so I have no idea what should I do about that exclamation sign. And of course, thank you so much for your help.